# Mirth database reader channel

Tags: mirth

I have configured mirth database reader channel and LLP sender channel. I am able to send messages and updating the details in the database. I want to update the database if any of the acknowledgement is failed. How can i achieve this? Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The On-Update statement will run after a message is processed, even if it errored on a destination. If you want to conditionally update based on an HL7 NACK, you can do that in the On-Update statement, but it would probably have to use JavaScript. Or, you can do this in a postprocessor:

```
if ($r('Destination 1').getStatus() == 'FAILURE' && /.*MSA.[AC][RE].*/.test($r('Destination 1').getMessage())) {
    // Update the database here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for the reply. I am trying the javascript way which you mentioned, but  i am facing a problem while updating the database, i am unable to pass the value of the id.               dbConn.executeUpdate("UPDATE generate_hl7 SET hl7_status = 'GENERATED' where id=?",$id); is this the right way i am doing?

Comment: Thanks Nick i had that wrong, i am able to execute using the javascript way. Thanks alot for your help.